# Отмеченный чекбокс и автоматический подсчет суммы

Tags: jquery, checkbox

> При запуске страницы есть отмеченные чекбоксы, как сделать чтобы автоматически к сумме добавлялись их значения?

```
    <h4>Стоимость</h4>
<p class="price">
  <span id="final_price_yslug">0</span> Руб.
</p>
<label for="yslygi">Верхняя торцевая перегородка</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="a1" id="yslygi" name="peregorodka"/>???<br/>
<label for="yslygi2">Борта у стены</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="a1" id="yslygi2" name="bort" />???

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> jQuery:

```
     $('input.a1').on("click",function(){

  var sum2 = 0;

  if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked')) {
   sum2 += 500;
  }
   if ($("#yslygi2").is(':checked')) {
   sum2 += 500;
  }
  $('#final_price_yslug').html(sum2);
});
$('input.a1').eq(0).click();
$('input.a1').eq(1).click();
```

> Полный код:

[код](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQR34D4GAWIK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызвать событие "клик" одного из этих чекбоксов.

```
$('input.a1').on("click",function(){
  ...
});
$('input.a1').eq(0).click();
// или через id
$("#yslygi").click();
```

Comment: Работает, а можно через id сделать?

Comment: @Лиана конечно, можно

Comment: Извините, можете еще мне подсказать? у меня вызов функции другой,в них я путаюсь, не получается под  него настроить  $('#count').keyup(calculate);
function calculate() {....}
$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
  });

Comment: @Лиана Минутку, я включу телепатический режим... Готово. У вас на странице больше одного элемента с `id="count"`. Используйте атрибут `class`.

Comment: Извините,что заморочила вам голову. Я поправила код, можете посмотреть?Никак не могу переделать под ваш код.

Comment: Можно прописать, чтобы автоматически менялся подсчет суммы при выбранном чекбоксе на странице и если на него нажмет пользователь? if ($("#yslygi").click()) sum += 100; 
  if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked')) sum += 100;

Comment: Впринципе получилось, но галочка не убирается и галочка убирается при выборе выпадающего списка https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Comment: @Лиана какая галочка должна убираться и когда?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76579/discussion-between--and-igor).

Comment: @Лиана уберите строчку `if ($("#yslygi").click()) sum += 100;` из кода

Comment: Я ваш ответ приняла как правильный, все верно работает, спасибо!